# how to write extract time epoch in AWS Athena SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have an SQL query as follows.

```
extract(epoch from ad.admittime) as admittime
```

I want to run this query in AWS Athena. AWS Athena SQL is based on Prestro and doesn't seem to be supporting `epoch`.

Is there anyway I can write the above query in AWS Athena or change it to get desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is `date_diff()`:

```
select date_diff('second', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00', ad.admittime) as admittime
```